# How to return nothing for mod_xml_curl?

Tags: xml, curl, freeswitch

Manual here http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_xml_curl says, that curl service should "return nothing" if it wants Freeswitch to process it's request based on static XMLs.

What exactly "return nothing" means?

0) Do not respond on client request (timeout)
1) Return HTTP 404 error?
2) Return HTTP 204 error (No Content)?
3) Return HTTP 200 with zero content?
4) Return HTTP 200 with any whitespaces but no XML tags?

Something else or some combination of the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is 'none of the above'; you should return

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
</document>
```

For completeness, if you want processing to end (i.e. no further bindings to be searched), the correct response is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
    <section name="result">
        <result status="not found" />
    </section>
</document>
```

Comment: have you been able to use method='GET' in mod_xml_curl? I keep getting POST methods :(

Comment: In the xml_curl.conf.xml binding configuration you can add the following parameter:   `<param name="method" value="GET"/>`